# Trying to add value and text from options from a dropdown box to a table but i cant add more than one?

Tags: javascript, html, combobox, row, inputbox

Okay this is pretty hard to explain but basically i have a dropdown box that is being created in javascript with a window.onload function. on this drop down box for option one, the value is 100 and the name is blueprint one, And the second option is called Blueprint Two and the value is 200. So then i select that and then choose the amount of it i want with an input box, that input box calls the function to do some maths, delete any previous rows of the dropdown box and replace it with the correct amount of blueprint one! so if you chose 5 of blueprint one it would look like :

Blueprint One *5 | 500
Instead of:
Blueprint One | 100
Blueprint One | 100
Blueprint One | 100
Blueprint One | 100
Blueprint One | 100

But the problem i am having is when i go to change to Blueprint two! so now lets say i want to have 2 of Blueprint two aswell as 5 of blueprint one so i select 2 on the input box, so what i want to happen is:

Blueprint One *5 | 500
Blueprint Two *2 | 400

What really happens is:

Blueprint Two *2 | 400

it deletes the blueprint one and replaces it with the blueprint two but i want both!
The code is underneath here.Thanks! 
JavaScript:

```
//function that is activated when the input box is increased/decreased
function bluePRTfunc(userVal)
{
    //userVal is getting (this) from the input box in the html
    userValVal = userVal.value;

    var table = document.getElementById('tableFull');
    //getting selected blueprint
    var selectedBp = document.getElementById("Blueprints");
    var bPText = selectedBp.options[selectedBp.selectedIndex].text;
    var bPValue = selectedBp.options[selectedBp.selectedIndex].value;
    //setting the value of the blueprint by multiplying it with the input value
    bPValue = bPValue * userValVal;
    // making the name of the blueprint have a *  and then the number of times the user has selected
    bPTextFinal = bPText +" * " + userValVal;
    //  for loop to go through the rows of the table
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        //getting cost that is in the table
        var subtractCost = table.childNodes[3].childNodes[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].innerHTML;
        //getting name that is in the table
        var subtractName = table.childNodes[3].childNodes[i].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML;
        //getting row that is in the table
        var tee = table.childNodes[3].childNodes[i].rowIndex;


        //deleting the row that is already there
        document.getElementById("tableFull").deleteRow(tee);
        //taking the cost that was on that row away from the total cost
        gTotalCost = gTotalCost - subtractCost;

    }
    else 
    {

    }


    }

    // adding the new products to the table and total cost
    addProduct(bPTextFinal, bPValue);
    renderProducts();
    blueprintInfoAdd();
    totalCostFunc();
}
```

HTML

```
<form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">


    <div class="pure-g">
        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
            <label for="Blueprints"></label>
            <select onclick="blueprintInfoAdd()" id="Blueprints" class="pure-input-1-2"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<form id="BPselectorForm" method="post" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned">
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
        <fieldset id="BPselectorFieldset">
            <div id="BPselectorDiv" class="pure-control-group">
                <input value="0" id="BPselector" onchange="bluePRTfunc(this)" type="number" min="0"> Amount</input>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: In your script there is an `else` statement without an `if` - missing part of the code?

Comment: yeah sorry no i accidentally removed the if part when i put it on here so that was not the problem but i have fixed it now so if anyone wants to see the fix then let me know

Comment: Of course we would, how else we would know, what's happening?

Comment: i mean ive fixed the problem i asked for help with the if else statement has nothing to do with it